# Big O of Quadruple Nested for loops

Tags: python, big-o, analysis

I'm trying to figure out what the Big O notation of this is. I know that the if this = n and that = m, the big O is O(mn), but if I have 4 in a row like this and worst case scenario it would run through all of them what would that do to my Big O notation.

```
def get_winner(self):      
    for this in range(self._this):
        for that in range(self._that - 2):
            # If statement here
                return

    for that in range(self._that):
        for this in range(self._this - 2):
            # If statement here
                return

    for this in range(self._this - 2):
        for that in range(self._that - 2):
            # If statement here
                return

    for this in range(self._this - 2):
        for that in range(self._that - 2):
            # If statement here
                return
```

Answer (score 1):

You just add the 4 for loops that aren't nested in each other, so worst case would be 4 * (n * m), which is O(4nm) = O(nm)

Answer (score 0):

It will be `O(4mn)`, but since for any constant a, `O(anm) = O(nm)`, so it will be `O(mn)` eventually.